# Calculate min_itemsize of Pandas HFStore column string before appending

Tags: pandas

I have csv files encoded in asian characters.... (let's UTF-8).

As I try to convert csv to Pandas HDFStore,

I need to handle the unicode and min_itemsize before appending in Pandas HDFSstore.

How can I know the max size of one dataframe column containing UTF-8 (asian characters) string ?

EDIT: asian text :

```
SMALL_AREA_NAME,PREF_NAME,COUPON_ID_hash

埼玉,埼玉県,6b263844241eea98c5a97f1335ea82af
新宿・高田馬場・中野・吉祥寺,東京都,e0a410ff611abefbfb57ca262dcdf42e
銀座・新橋・東京・上野,東京都,b286f6fb50a4f849e4382c9752405d7a
```

EDIT 2:
It seems unicode has issues with HDFStore append returns an error :
(Python 2.7 , cannot use Python 3 due to other packages conflicts...)

```
  for col in col_list :
     df_i[col] = df_i[col].map(lambda x:  x.encode('utf-8'))
     max_size= df_i[col].str.len().max() 

  store.append(tablename, df_i, format='table', encoding="utf-8", min_itemsize=max_size)
```

return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-69-e96ff71ee569>", line 26, in <module>
    store.append(tablename, df_i, format='table', encoding="utf-8", min_itemsize=max_size)
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 919, in append
    **kwargs)
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1264, in _write_to_group
    s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3787, in write
    **kwargs)
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3460, in create_axes
    raise e
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: So when you execute `df.SMALL_AREA_NAME.str.len().max()` for your small CSV - does it work correctly?

Comment: AFAIK `read_csv()` per default reads strings in UTF-8 encoding, so you shouldn't try to do it again - try to remove the line containing : `df_i[col].map(lambda x:  x.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: beside this `min_itemsize` - should be a dictionary. Example: `min_itemsize={'column_name': max_size}`

Comment: by removing x.encode :TypeError: [unicode] is not implemented as a table column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** test under Python 2.7

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   a       b
0  1      hi
1  2  привіт
2  3   Grüßi

In [3]: store = pd.HDFStore('d:/temp/test_py27.h5')

In [4]: store.append('test', df)

In [5]: store.get_storer('test').table
Out[5]:
/test/table (Table(3,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Int64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=1),
  "values_block_1": StringCol(itemsize=12, shape=(1,), dflt='', pos=2)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (2340,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
```

**Old answer:**

you can use `Series.str.len().max()`:

Demo:

```
In [91]: df
Out[91]:
                    A
0         aaa.bbbbbbb
1  ccc,xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2           xxxxx.zzz

In [92]: df.A.str.len()
Out[92]:
0    11
1    18
2     9
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [93]: df.A.str.len().max()
Out[93]: 18
```

Comment: Does len take into account asian character size ? (in unicode / utf-8) ?

Comment: @Tensor, can you post a few strings with asian characters?

Comment: @Tensor, hmmm... it should be able to write in UTF-8... How do you do this?

Comment: Python 2.7 (cannot use Python 3 due other package conflict...).

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this one works in Python 2.7: (removing the last encoding)

```
  for col in col_list :
     df_i[col] = df_i[col].map(lambda x:  str(x.encode('utf-8')))
     max_size= df_i[col].str.len().max() 

  store.append(tablename, df_i, format='table', min_itemsize=max_size)
```